# Trying to kind of pivot but not really?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data like this:

```
Data = {'codes': ['123456', '789654789', '789654789', '54126', '123456'],    
        'names': ['google.com', 'reddit.com', 'bbc.com', 'google.com', 'google.com']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['codes','names'])
```

My desired result is this:

```
Data = {'codes': ['123456', '789654789', '54126'],    
        'names': ['(2)google.com', '(1)reddit.com|(1)bbc.com', '(1)google.com']
        }



df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['codes','names'])
```

My idea is to do not have specific row for each code/domain combination, but just to leave unique codes in the first column, and in the second column put a string, witch would say how manny entries of specific domain where associated with it and all domains separated by comma in that same string. 
Right now I am using a list `df.codes.unique()' and putting this into loop and constructing a string inside that loop. Once I ended with one code, then I go on to another and to that same thing again. I have millions of lines and this approach is very slow. Is there any effective way..?

Comment: can you post your code so that we can try to optimize it?

Comment: Give me a one minute!

Answer (score 0):

First use a [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to do the calculations and then join the non-zero sums with the column names. The last line just converts the result series to a dataframe as per your question:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df.codes, df.names)
result = ct.apply(lambda row: '|'.join(list(filter(None,map((lambda value,colName: '({}){}'.format(value, colName) if value > 0 else ''), row, ct.columns.values)))), axis = 1)
res_df = result.reset_index().rename(columns = {0: 'names'})
```

This gives the following result:

```
       codes                     names
0     123456             (2)google.com
1      54126             (1)google.com
2  789654789  (1)bbc.com|(1)reddit.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = {'codes': ['123456', '789654789', '789654789', '54126', '123456'],
        'names': ['google.com', 'reddit.com', 'bbc.com', 'google.com', 'google.com']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['codes','names'])

df=df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
df['count']=df['count'].astype(str)+' '+df['names']
df = df.sort_values('names') .groupby('codes', sort=False)['count'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
print(df)
       codes                   count
0  789654789  1 bbc.com,1 reddit.com
1     123456            2 google.com
2      54126            1 google.com
```